# Can DESCRIBE FORMATTED syntax be embedded in SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, impala, vertica

The syntax DESCRIBE FROMATTED can show a table's structure, but it cannot be embedded to normal statement; is there some tricky way to do it?

For example, this shows the table1 information structure, returned as a table (but SQL statement does not think so)

```
DESCRIBE FROMATTED `table1`
```

But this doesn't work:

```
SELECT * FROM (DESCRIBE FORMATTED `table1`)
```

Is there a way to enable it?

Comment: As per my knowledge `No`. Is there any reason you don't want to get this information from `Information_Schema` ?

Comment: You tagged this question mysql, impala, and vertica. Which implementation are you really asking about? MySQL does not have a `DESCRIBE FORMATTED` command.

Comment: Neither does `DESCRIBE FORMATTED` exist in Vertica. For a detailed report on the database objects that make a table, you need to run:`SELECT EXPORT_OBJECTS('','schema.table')` .

Comment: I think OP is talking about Impala. And you no, you cant use it in a select clause. But you can use a python to store this data in table. and then run a select clause.